# How to rename files, removing all characters between certain values

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have a list of 15.000 documents where I need to remove a certain piece of text from the name.

The name structure is always: `[xxx]_(xxx)_xxx.extension`

I am trying to remove the `(xxx)_` part of the filename. The length of xxx is variable.

I've only found ways to replace certain pieces of text or remove fixed pieces of text. Any help or guidelines are appreciated.

Comment: Are the brackets (`[]` and `()`) really part of the file name?

Comment: @dbenham, yes they are. Here's an example: `[124786]_(12424)_Name of the file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [JREN.BAT - a regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Assuming you have JREN.BAT in a folder that resides within your PATH, then all you need is the following command from the command line:

```
jren "^(\[.*?\]_)\(.*?\)_" "$1"
```

The command looks for file names in the current directory that begin with `[*]_(*)_` and removes the `(*)_` portion.

Use `CALL JREN` if you put the command in a batch script.

You can add the `/P` option to specify a path different than the current directory, and the `/S` option to iterate all sub-directories.

You can use `jren /??` to access the extensive documentation. Press `<Enter>` to advance the help one line at a time, or `<space>` to advance one screen page at a time. Or use `jren /?` to get the entire help dumped to screen immediately.

Comment: EDIT - I forgot to escape the `[]` meta characters.

Comment: how do you install JREN.bat? Do I add all the code from the first post in your link to a text file and then I use a command prompt (using CD to get into the folder) and then run that line?

Comment: @CustomX - follow the link, and copy the code into a file named JREN.BAT. I recommend putting the script in a file that is listed in your PATH - I have a folder named C:\UTILS. But you don't have to do that. If it is in your current directory, then you can simply use JREN. But if it is not in your current directory, and not in your PATH, then you will need to specify the path to JREN.BAT when you call it.

Comment: Ooh thank you very much! I'll try it tomorrow morning at work!

Comment: Dave worked great! I just noticed a flaw on my end, removing that middle piece creates duplicate file names and thus not everything is updated. You wouldn't know how I could overcome this one would you?

Answer (score 2):

that's a job for `for`:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b "[*]_(*)_*.extension"') do @echo %%a_%%c  [removed "%%b"]
```

How it works:

it disassembles your filenames into three parts, based on a delimiter (`_` here): `firstpart_secondpart_thirdpart`, then reassembling it by mounting the first and third part together.

If you want to rename them (for example), instead of just `echo`ing, you can do: `ren "%%a_%%b_%%c" "%%a_%%c"`

Comment: what will happen if ´_´ is used inside the third part? So I just add that code to a .bat file and insert the correct directory?

Comment: @CustomX - The `tokens=1,2,*` handles that - it doesn't break at `_` in the 3rd token, so the 3rd token is complete.

Comment: This will mistakenly rename files that don't match the template. Better to use `dir /b [*]_(*)_*.extension`

Comment: This will also have problems if `_` appears within `[...]` or `(...)`

Comment: @dbenham, thanks for the update! At a glance, it doesn't seem like `[...]` and `(...)` contain `_` at the moment, but not sure about this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim multiple file names, you can try this using PowerShell.
1. Navigate to the directory where the files to rename are.
2. Excecute the following command.

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-N) + $_.Extension}
```

where N in "length-N" is the number of characters you want to trim, from the last one, without counting the extension file.

**Example:**

I restored my files after a backup in Windows 10 and every document appeared with some extra characters, showing the day and time when I made the back up.

being *FileName (2020_02_13 12_33_22 UTC).extension*, I needed to trim everything between the parenthesis and take *FileName.extension*

So I have to trim 26 characters in every filename. Then N = 26

1) I open PowerShell and navigate to the folder where I will excecute the script.
2) I excecute the following script

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-26) + $_.Extension}
```

*Take care using this command, because it doesn't follow any parameters except to trim a given number of characters.*